# SQL Azure Full Text search when searching for text with leading 0's

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have a large SQL Azure database with extensive full text search data.  This works perfect for most searches except when searching for text based number that have leading 0s.   What happens is that when I search for 00123 it is searching for 123*  So essentially it is ignoring my leading 0's.   Below is an example of what I have tried.

WHERE Contains(FullTextDatabaseField, '"00123*"')

I have tried other variations with and without the astericks, I have tried ContainsTable and every variation of full text search.

I had seen in SQL 2012 you could upload some sort of custom dictionary that indicated which words should be treated as words.   However in SQL Azure I am not seeing any such option.

With this search the way it is, I am getting a ton of not relevant results.   Unfortunately this kind of search is pretty common.   There are a series of codes in our data and some of them unfortunately have leading 0s.   is there a way to force full text on SQL Azure to treat a string absolutely literally or is there a way to upload a custom dictionary of common search terms that you want treated literally.   I wish it would quit trying to be so helpful.   THis is annoying.

Comment: Allow me time to find some help. I may not be able to find help until Monday. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of SQL Server and Azure SQL Database not taking leading zeros into account is old and goes back to SQL Server 2008 as explained on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c774177b-f16c-4608-8dd0-8c4015515a14/leading-zeroes-ignored-in-freetext-search-mssql-2010?forum=sqlsearch) thread. This is by design.

A workaround for SQL Server may be using [Custom Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/customize-the-behavior-of-word-breakers-with-a-custom-dictionary) but this seems to be not an option for Azure SQL Database.